# hide some elements on front befor user have authorization

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a problem with authorization. On client side I used this code

```
if (_.isNull(window.localStorage.getItem("username"))) {
      MEDService.testUser($scope.user)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
       if (data == "OK") {
        window.localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.user.username);
        window.localStorage.setItem("password", $scope.user.password);
        $rootScope.user = $scope.user;
        $location.path('/');
       } else {
       alert('Incorrect! Please check your username and password.');
       }
```

and before success login I want to hide some elements on front. Please advice me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set flag inside your controller scope, & then use that flag in `ng-show`/`ng-if`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="isLoaded">
    Content
</div>
```

**Code**

```
if (_.isNull(window.localStorage.getItem("username"))) {
      //before loading set it to false
      $scope.isLoaded = false;
      MEDService.testUser($scope.user)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
       if (data == "OK") {
        window.localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.user.username);
        window.localStorage.setItem("password", $scope.user.password);
        $rootScope.user = $scope.user;
        $scope.isLoaded = true;
        //after loaded set it to true
        $location.path('/');
       } else {
       alert('Incorrect! Please check your username and password.');
}
```

Comment: ok, and how i can use value of flag (true - false) on front?
for example i want to hide md-sidenav
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">

Comment: @OlgaK Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for your comment , but it's getting bad...after login div is not show

Comment: you should add some loading icon instead of that `div` which will have some height. indirectly that will tell user that something is going on there

Comment: code:
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left"  ng-if="isLoaded">
    <div ng-controller="LeftCtrl" ng-click="close()">
      <md-toolbar id="toolbar">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Menu</h1>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content >
        <a class="menu-item menu-sub-item md-menu-item" ng-click="menu.toggleSelectPage(page)" ng-repeat="page in menu.pages" ng-href="#{{page.url}}" md-highlight="menu.isPageSelected(page)" md-ink-ripple="#bbb">  
          <span > {{page.discription}} </span> 
        </a>
      </md-content>
    </div>
  </md-sidenav>